# bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls not working

Tags: apache, nutch

I just followed the tutorial to setup Nutch from [NutchWiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial).

Downloaded Nutch 2.x src and set all configurations.
The problem occurs when I just started to crawl. 
When I run this code : `bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls` I am getting an error message like this : `Unrecognized arg urls`
I just followed all steps in the tutorial, created directories, made changes to configuration files etc. And I also have a query that there is no crawldb directory in the apache-nutch-2.x/runtime/local/ Is it automatically generated or need to manually generate it ?
Any help to this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going through the same problem. The documentation seems to be outdated. It is for 1.x .

For 2.x I have tried the following and it worked for me.

```
bin/nutch inject urls
```

Hope it helps.